# Итератор принимает значение нуля

Tags: c++, итераторы

```
 cout << "Реализация списка: " << endl;
    int skdf = rand()%10 +20;
    vector<int> spisok(skdf);
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    it = spisok.begin();
    for(advance(it, 0); it != spisok.end(); it++)
    {
        *it = rand()%100 -50;
    }
    int spisok_summa = 0;
    for(advance(it, 0); it != spisok.end(); it++)
    {
        spisok_summa += *it;
    }
    cout << spisok_summa << " - сумма чисел в списке" << endl;
    cout << spisok_summa/skdf << " - среднее арифмитическое списка" << endl;
    
    advance(it, 0);
    while(*it < 0)
        it++;
    int min1 = 0;
    min1 = *it;
    for(it; it != spisok.end(); it++)
    {
        if(*it > 0 and *it < min1)
            min1 = *it;
    }
    cout << min1 << " - наименьшее положительное число списка" << endl;
    
    for(advance(it, 0); it != spisok.end(); it++)
    {
        if(*it > 0)
            *it = min1*min1;
        cout << *it << " - элемент списка" << endl;
    }
```

Нужно заменить каждое положительное число квадратом минимального положительного. Подскажите, почему у меня все по нулям выводится?

> Реализация списка:
>
> 0 - сумма чисел в списке
>
> 0 - среднее арифмитическое списка
>
> 0 - наименьшее положительное число списка
>
> Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что

```
advance(it, 0);
```

**не** выставляет итератор на начало. Так что вы пытаетесь работать с итератором, указывающим за конец списка...

Вот тут

```
cout << spisok_summa/skdf
```

у вас *целочисленное деление*, с отбрасыванием дробной части результата... С использованием случайного равномерного заполнения в вашем диапазоне скорее всего получится 0.

Вот так

```
while(*it < 0)
```

я бы не рекомендовал поступать — а вдруг в списке будут *только* отрицательные значения?...

Замените соответствующий фрагмент вот таким:

```
vector<int>::iterator it;

for(it = spisok.begin(); it != spisok.end(); it++)
{
    cout << (*it = rand()%100 -50) << "  ";
}
cout << endl;

int spisok_summa = 0;

for(it = spisok.begin(); it != spisok.end(); it++)
{
    spisok_summa += *it;
}

cout << spisok_summa << " - сумма чисел в списке" << endl;
cout << double(spisok_summa)/skdf << " - среднее арифмитическое списка" << endl;

it = spisok.begin();
while(*it < 0)
    it++;
```

Comment: а как можно поставить итератор на начало?

Comment: `it = spisok.begin();`

Answer (score 0):

Чем Вас не устраивает такой вариант:

```
for (auto elem : spisok) {
    spisok_summa += elem;
}
cout << spisok_summa << " - сумма чисел в списке" << endl;
cout << double(spisok_summa)/skdf << " - среднее арифмитическое списка" << endl;
```